# how to fix- Control may reach end of non-void function

Tags: c, cs50

I meet problem during cs50 class, I have to write binary search function.
When trying to run code this message appear: `control may reach end of non-void function`. I tried to fix by adding at last line `return false` but this makes output always `false`. Please give me some tips.

Here is my code:

```
bool search_r(int value, int values[], int l, int r) {
    int v = values[(l + r) / 2];
    int right = r;
    int left = l;
    if ((l + r) / 2 > 0) {
        if (v == value) {
            return true;
        } else 
        if (v > value) {
            right = ((l + r) / 2);
            search_r(value, values, left, right);
        } else
        if (v < value) {
            left = ((l + r) / 2);
            search_r(value, values, left, right);
        }
    } else {
        return false;
    }         
}
```

Comment: Any reason you don't return the result of the recursions?

Comment: Or you might be looking for [CS50 SE](//cs50.stackexchange.com).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your function has several problems:

- You must return the values from the recursive calls to `search_r()`. This error is causing the warning as the function does not have a `return` statement after the nested `if` statements. Making it `return false;` at the end is incorrect as the recursive call should return `true` if the `value` is found.
- `(l + r) / 2` may overflow if `l` or `r` is very large. The result would be incorrect in this case. The correct way to compute the middle index is `l + (r - l) / 2`.
- The test for termination is not `(l + r) / 2 > 0`, which only tests if the middle index is `> 0`.  Instead use `l < r`, ie. if the range is not empty, `l` being included and `r` excluded.
- The test `if (v < value)` is redundant, you already tested for `v == value` and `v > value`.
- Using `l` as a variable name is somewhat confusing as it is visually very similar to `1`, especially for fixed pitch fonts used for code.

Here is a corrected version:

```
bool search_r(int value, int values[], int left, int right) {
    if (left < right) {
        int middle = left + (right - left) / 2;
        int v = values[middle];
        if (v == value) {
            return true;
        } else
        if (v > value) {
            return search_r(value, values, left, middle);
        } else {
            return search_r(value, values, middle + 1, right);
        }
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Finally, the function can be implemented as a loop instead of using recursion.  The compiler is likely to generate the same code since the recursion is terminal, but some people find one way more intuitive than the other:

```
bool search_r(int value, int values[], int left, int right) {
    while (left < right) {
        int middle = left + (right - left) / 2;
        int v = values[middle];
        if (v == value) {
            return true;
        } else
        if (v > value) {
            right = middle;
        } else {
            left = middle + 1;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

In both cases, the function should be called this way, where `length` is the number of elements of `array`.

```
bool found = search_r(value, array, 0, length);
```

Answer (score 0):

The last `else` is not necessary, if you simply return `false` it will do exactly what you want. But you should probably return `true` inside the `if` branch. Or make the function not return at all, since you are not using the return value anyway, and if it's always `false` it's not very useful anyway.

Comment: "it will be exactly the same" and make the error go away :)

Comment: Just like mithilesh's answer, this would fix the warning, but not the algorithmic flaw. The function would return false for all but a single value in the array.

Comment: @chqrlie Perhaps you're right. I did not focus on what the function does, just the reason of the warning.

Answer (score 0):

Your function:

```
bool search_r(int value, int values[], int left, int right)
```

Indicates that a **bool** will be returned.  I think @chqrlie has an excellent response to this.

You should have a some default value returned that is not affected by any loops or conditionals in case those aren't met.

Answer (score -1):

Consider the condition that the if condition is not satisfied and the program finishes without giving a return value. Now it is impossible because of your else condition.But the compiler does not know that and hence wants to make sure that the function returns a value since it is a non-void function.
Removing the else condition and simply adding

```
return false;
```

at the end of your program will solve the problem.

Comment: This would fix the warning, but not the algorithmic flaw. The function would return false for all but a single value in the array.